# Redirecting non-www to www, but keeping other sub-domains intact

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have 5 web pages with different domain names. Each of them uses the same directory and the same `.htaccess` file. I've redirected `non www` urls to `www` with this lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now I would like to keep redirecting non wwws to wwws, but I would also like to keep other subdomains without www. For example:
`domain1.com` should redirect to `www.domain1.com` and
`subdomain1.domain1.com` should still be `subdomain1.domain1.com` and should not redirect to `www.subdomain1.domain1.com`.

Keep in mind I have 5 webpages hosted from the same directory and there are more to come. I don't want to change `.htaccess` file everytime there is a page added.

I don't want to mess up my `.htaccess` file so I need your help!

PS: Is there a possibility to take https into account. 
`https://domain.com` to `https://www.domain.com`
`http://domain.com` to `http://www.domain.com`
`https://sub.domain.com` to `https://sub.domain.com`
`http://sub.domain.com` to `http://sub.domain.com`

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just target your rule for main domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

`RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|` and `%1` is used to maintain `http/https` in target URL.

Make sure to clear your browser cache when testing this change.

Comment: this works for one domain only. Is it possible to make it work for every domain that is assigned to the same directory?